# How do I set CSV header in camel DSL?

Tags: apache-camel

I have one CSV file without header which is containing two value like

`"lenovo","30000"`

I want to set header in first row using camel DSL and pass it to another route, header is like:

`"laptop","price"`

My DSL route:

```
from("file:...?fileName=file1.csv&noop=true")
   //Something I want to include string like this
   .addLineInBody("laptop"+"price").append("\n")
   .to("file:../?fileName=output.csv");
```

How can I do this in camel DSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not fully understand your header-problem. If you want to just prepend the CSV file with a static header a save it again as CSV you could simply use a Java bean to prepend the message body.

If you want to convert CSV to a data structure or vice versa you should check out the Camel CSV documentation: http://camel.apache.org/csv.html

**Update:** 
You can write a java bean like this. The important part is the `@Body` Camel annotation to inject the message body into the method. See http://camel.apache.org/parameter-binding-annotations.html for more information about this.
Do the body manipulation as you like.

```
public class CsvHeaderEnricher {
    public String enrichCsvHeader(@Body String messageBody) {
        String enrichedBody = "YourHeader" + messageBody;
        return enrichedBody;
    }
}
```

Then you can call the bean in your route like this:

```
from("file:...?fileName=file1.csv&noop=true")
    .bean(new CsvHeaderEnricher())
    .to("file:../?fileName=output.csv");
```

- You can also register the bean in the Spring context, autowire it into the Route class and use an instance variable instead of `new`
- As long as your bean contains only one method, you don't need to tell Camel what method to use

Comment: I updated my question I wish it is more understandable.